# What would be best the best way for multiple companies to consolidate their demand forecasting together?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, business-intelligence

I am currently reading up on my demand forecasting knowledge and had this question where I can't seem to find a quick answer for.

Let's say you have a couple of stores/restaurants/etc that sell more or less the same products. Each of these has some form of forecasting that they do for a certain product for their own business.

Let's say that these managers get together and consider collaborating on forecasting their daily demand for a product, let's say a certain book, how would they best approach this? How would the best aggregate number be calculated that would be good enough?

My idea is this, and please correct me if I am wrong as this is why I am asking the question.

As each business already has their own forecast for a certain period, you could just add up all the forecasts to get a total and then divide the forecast for each business by the total giving each a certain %.
Then the historic data needs to be combined and aggregated (let's say hypothetically it's all in the same format and that this is easy to do). This combined, aggregated data then gets analyzed and a forecast is made on the demand. After getting the results of said forecast, the forecast is then divided as per the %'s calculated earlier.

Is it this "simple" or am I missing something where this approach would not work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well I guess there’s not really something that I need. It’s just a theoretical hypothetical question about how multiple business owners could leverage their historic data to get an aggregated demand forecasted.

Comment: I think this is a clear question; it's basically a hierarchical modeling question, really.